# Slider bindBidirectional

Tags: javafx, bind

Hi I'm stuck in situation where to use bidirectional binding for 2 sliders valueProperty

The task is:  there's 2 sliders each of them has maximum value 100 
But this value is divided between these 2 sliders,  for example if you move first slider to value 20 then second slider value must be 80  and vice versa.

I know this should be done with bind bidirectional but how can I bind expression to the property?

```
slider1.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(slider2.getMax() - slider2.valueProperty());  ???
```

Any help will be highly appriciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with bidirectional binding: you need to use two listeners:

```
slider1.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> 
    slider2.setValue(slider2.getMax() - newValue.doubleValue()));

slider2.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> 
    slider1.setValue(slider1.getMax() - newValue.doubleValue()));
```

SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ConverselyBoundSliders extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Slider slider1 = new Slider(0, 100, 50);
        Slider slider2 = new Slider(0, 100, 50);

        slider1.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> 
            slider2.setValue(slider2.getMax() - newValue.doubleValue()));

        slider2.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> 
            slider1.setValue(slider1.getMax() - newValue.doubleValue()));

        VBox root = new VBox(5, slider1, slider2);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(12));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This seems to work just fine without any infinite recursion occurring; however since it involves floating-point arithmetic and comparisons for that to be true, you might want to make sure that rounding errors in the `slider.getMax() - newValue.doubleValue()` calculation don't end up with each listener calling the other without escaping from the recursion. The following is a bullet-proof way to do it:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ConverselyBoundSliders extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Slider slider1 = new Slider(0, 100, 50);
        Slider slider2 = new Slider(0, 100, 50);

        new ConverseSliderBinding(slider1, slider2);

        VBox root = new VBox(5, slider1, slider2);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(12));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static class ConverseSliderBinding {
        private ChangeListener<Number> listener1 ;
        private ChangeListener<Number> listener2 ;

        private final Slider slider1 ;
        private final Slider slider2 ;

        private boolean adjusting ;

        public ConverseSliderBinding(Slider slider1, Slider slider2) {
            this.slider1 = slider1 ;
            this.slider2 = slider2 ;

            listener1 = (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if (adjusting) return ;
                adjusting = true ;
                slider2.setValue(slider2.getMax() - newValue.doubleValue());
                adjusting = false ;
            };

            listener2 = (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if (adjusting) return ;
                adjusting = true ;
                slider1.setValue(slider1.getMax() - newValue.doubleValue());
                adjusting = false ;
            };

            slider1.valueProperty().addListener(listener1);
            slider2.valueProperty().addListener(listener2);
        }

        public void dispose() {
            slider1.valueProperty().removeListener(listener1);
            slider2.valueProperty().removeListener(listener2);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks James_D.